# Escaping single quotes in Response.Write

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm not a Asp.Net developer but I happen to work on a JavaScript side of code-base that has some simple Asp.Net in there as well. I need to escape a dynamic text before it sets for a JavaScript object property:

```
Text: '<% =_serviceMessageText %>'
```

I tried to use `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` but it didn't work and actually didn't really get what should I expect from it. I was wondering if there are any simple ways to escape single quotes, possibly avoiding regex.

NB: The actual text is already encoded, so single quotes are stored as `&#39;`, but when retrieved represented as actual single quote character, causing JavaScript parse error.

**Update**

Perhaps I should change the JavaScript side to:

```
Text: "<% =_serviceMessageText %>"
```

And use `Server.HTMLEncode` to escape double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct; use double quote `""` to escape/delimit server side string and single quotes should be used for delimiting client side strings. It should be rather

```
"<% =_serviceMessageText %>"
```